# Symfony - creation of a "table" form

Tags: php, symfony

I am under symfony 5, on an application already in production on which I would like to add a screen allowing to modify several lines of the same table at once, in the same "POST" message, with one and the same "send" button.

The different fields must be contained inside a single form tag:

```
<form name="modif_todo_liste" method="post">
...
</form>
```

I tried different things including creating a table with different views based on the same template form:

```
foreach($todos as $v){
    $form_tab[]=$this->createForm(ModifTodoListeType::class,$v)->createView();
}
```

that I render in twig:

```
{% for form in form_tab %}
    {{ form_start(form) }}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ form_row(form.Denomination) }}</td>
            <td>{{ form_row(form.Nbr) }}</td>
            <td>{{ form_row(form.CIS) }}</td>
            <td>{{ form_row(form.Label) }}</td>
            <td>{{ form_row(form.BN_Label) }}</td>
            <td>{{ form_row(form.ATC7) }}</td>
            <td>{{ form_row(form.Categorie) }}</td>
        </tr>
    {{ form_end(form) }}
{% endfor %}
```

visually this corresponds to what I would like, but impossible to validate everything at once because, it is all the lines are not included in the same form:

[image]

Does anyone know of an easy way to make this form that will be "flushable" in the controller afterwards?

Otherwise I will do a more classic solution, I pass an array containing my entire table to twig, in the view I build a form by looping over the array. And in the controller I will take care of the update.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can create the whole form containing different fields using Symfony forms.
You can even map the attributes to the entity directly, so the update is taken care of on the `handleRequest` method called on the form. (the entity is updated, you still need to save it to the database)

[Symfony forms docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#creating-form-classes)

If the fields are dependent on some array in the controller, you can also build the form in the controller like [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#creating-forms-in-controllers).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I know these symfony practices, this is why I would like to use handleRequest(), and the entity->flush().

Entity represents a line from a table (or from some tables), so my aim is to update many lines from the same form, with the same submit button, and so in the same data return with the ->handleRequest()

According to my screenshot (the table with the green and grey lines), I would like to show a form with différents entities with only one submit button

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
    {% for form in form_tab %}

    <tr>
        <td>{{ form_row(form.Denomination) }}</td>
        <td>{{ form_row(form.Nbr) }}</td>
        <td>{{ form_row(form.CIS) }}</td>
        <td>{{ form_row(form.Label) }}</td>
        <td>{{ form_row(form.BN_Label) }}</td>
        <td>{{ form_row(form.ATC7) }}</td>
        <td>{{ form_row(form.Categorie) }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```